# Mutiny: loop over a collection every second

Tags: java, mutiny

I'm trying to invoke a set of Web Services every second using Mutiny which is a Java Streaming API.
The following, works to invoke the callWebService method every second, but it passes a counter to the callWebService method:

```
List data = new ArrayList();
data.add("http://host/service1");
data.add("http://host/service2");
data.add("http://host/service3");
Multi.createFrom().ticks().every(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).map
        (n -> callWebService(n)
        )
```

Next, I've tried to plug in an iterable function, to loop over the List of services:

```
Multi.createFrom().ticks().every(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).iterable(data).map
        (n -> callWebService(data)
        )
```

Unfortunately, it looks like a Long is required in the iteration. Can you suggest a way to iterate over the List every second, invoking the callWebService method?

Comment: What is `callWebService()`? Is this a function you wrote? Or is it something from the mutiny api?

Comment: Also what do you *want* to do here? What do you want to pass to `callWebService()`?

Comment: Hi! callWebService is a function I have written. Instead of passing the counter (n), I'd like to pass an item from the list (e.g. http://host/service1)

Comment: Then just get an item from the list: `callwebService(data.get(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this more complicated than necessary. You can just get an item from the data list to pass to `callWebService()`:

```
Multi.createFrom().ticks().every(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).map
        (n -> callWebService(data.get(n))
        )
```